# Consider the set $X=\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$and its bases for a topology on $X$

Tags: general-topology

$B=\{\{a\},\{c\},\{c,d\},\{b,c,e,f\}\}$ is not a basis for a topology on $X $because the union of the members of this basis would generate a topology with $\{a,b,d,e,f\}$ and $\{b,c,d\}$ but not $\{b,d\}$ which would be their intersection.

$B=\{\{c\},\{d\},\{c,d,e\},\{a,b,e,f\}\}$ is not a basis for a topology on $X$ because the union of the members of this basis would generate a topology with $\{c,d,e\}$ and $\{a,b,d,e,f\}$ but not $\{d,e\}$ which would be their intersection.

Alternatively, $\{\{a\},\{b\},\{c,d\},\{a,d,e,f\}\}$ and $\{\{a,b\},\{c,d\},\{e,f\}\}$ are basis for a topology on $X$.

Is this correct or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first family, $B=\big\{\{a\},\{c\},\{c,d\},\{b,c,e,f\}\big\}$, *is* a base for a topology on $X$. Here is a picture of the space, showing the members of $B$: clearly the intersection of any two members of $B$ is either empty or a member of $B$, so $B$ is certainly a base for a topology.

[image: The space.]

That topology is

$$\big\{\varnothing, X,\{a\},\{c\},\{c,d\},\{a,c,d\},\{b,c,e,f\},\{a,b,c,e,f\},\{b,c,d,e,f\}\big\}\;.$$

Your answer to the second question is correct, but you can make it even simpler: $\{c,d,e\}$ and $\{a,b,e,f\}$ are in $B$, but $\{c,d,e\}\cap\{a,b,e,f\}=\{e\}$ is not the union of members of $B$.

It is *not* true that the family $\big\{\{a\},\{b\},\{c,d\},\{a,d,e,f\}\big\}$ is a base for a topology on $X$, because $\{c,d\}\cap\{a,d,e,f\}=\{d\}$ is not the union of members of the family.

It is true, however, that $\big\{\{a,b\},\{c,d\},\{e,f\}\big\}$ is a base for a topology on $X$.